Is it correct to retrieve the liveChatId from the stream being broadcast on YouTube and send it back to our backend server for processing?
We've successfully confirmed that our backend server can stream live video to YouTube's RTMP server using only the stream key, without going through the YouTube Live API. In this case, is it correct to retrieve the liveChatId from the stream that is being broadcasted on YouTube and send it back to our backend server for processing?
